# Access db without leaving empty db behind.[node-mongodb-native]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I want to make sure some database does not yet exist in mongodb but anytime I access db object an empty database is created.

**Using [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver:**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/nonexistingdb", function(err, db) {
    db.eval('db.getMongo().getDBNames();',function(err, dbnames) {
        console.log(dbnames);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

+

```
$ mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames();"
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
local
```

**It does not act like that when using [mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/):**

```
$ cat > byshell.js
server = new Mongo();
db = server.getDB("nonexistentdb");
dbnames = server.getDBNames();
print(dbnames);
```

+

```
$ mongo --nodb byshell.js 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
local
```

+

```
$ mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames();"
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
local
```

What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Since calling `MongoClient.connect` with a database name is analogous to typing `use dbname` in the mongo CLI, such that the act of connecting will create the database if it does not exist, I'd imagine the only way to assure that a specific database didn't exist after connecting would be to call `db.dropDatabase` after connecting to it, but would really defeat the purpose of the connect call.

### Update

After digging into the code, it seems that one of the last things `MongoClient.connect` does is to open the database named in its connection URI, which clearly has the side-effect of creating the database if it doesn't exist. (See line 371 or so in `node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js`)

So it's interesting to note that by using `MongoClient.connect`, you have no choice but to accept this behavior, since it *requires* that you include a `dbname` as part of the Mongo Connection String URI you must provide, which is counter to the [official definition](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) of such things.

So it would appear that if you don't wish to *automagically* create non-existent databases when connecting to Mongo, you shouldn't rely on the official `mongodb.js` driver and its MongoClient API.

You might try [mongojs](https://npmjs.org/package/mongojs) which wraps the `mongodb.js` driver with an API that supports more of a Mongo Shell metaphor, as in:

```
var util=require('util'),
    mongojs=require('mongojs'),
    connectionUriWithoutDb='localhost/', // *see note below.
    db=mongojs(connectionUriWithoutDb);

db.runCommand({ping:1},function(err,res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('result: %s', util.inspect(res));
    db.close();
});
```

which prints to the console:

```
result: { ok: 1 }
```

and doesn't create a database.

- Note that if you choose to connect this way, you must remember to end your Connection String URI with a slash to inform the underlying `mongodb.js` driver that you're specifying a hostname rather than a database name *which happens to contain periods*.

Without the slash, `mongodb.js` throws an exception (per `validateDatabaseName` at line 216 of `node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js`) since database names must not contain spaces, periods, dollar-signs, and either forward or backward slashes.

Oddly enough, this test is of the Array.prototype.indexOf variety on a list of those five characters, rather than using a RegExp which would have forbade the use of any character other than those allowed.

My next database name surely must contain several newlines, at least one bell, and a tab or two. ;)

Comment: Well `use dbname` does not leave it behind unless you do insert, update or other write operation. It is created when you use/connect to it but only for this session unless you write to it. I do realize that this is not uscase found to often but if they considered it in shell I'd expect it to be the same in api.